# Как создать массив, который содержит массив словарей?

Tags: массивы, swift, словари

То, что я хочу сделать можно представить так:

```
+2011
+2012
+2013
-2014
     +1
     +2
     +3
     -4
       "maxTemp":"23.4"
       "minTemp":"3.1"
       "sunnyDays":"12"
```

Года и месяцы типа String.

Я имею базовое представление о массивах и словарях, но я еще новичок, и эта конструкция еще сложновата для меня. 
У меня есть догадка как создать ее, но я не знаю как потом добавлять данные на разных уровнях. 
`var data = [[[String:String]]]()` или

```
var data = Array<Array<Dictionary<String, String>>>()
```

Как это написать в Swift3? И как потом добавлять новый год, месяц и данные в эту конструкцию?

Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала я бы создал объект

```
class Weather {
    var maxTemp: Double!
    var minTemp: Double!
    var sunnyDays: Int!

    init (_ maxTemp: Double, minTemp: Double, sunnyDays: Int) {
        self.maxTemp = maxTemp
        self.minTemp = minTemp
        self.sunnyDays = sunnyDays
    }
}
```

Далее я бы создал dictionary в котором хранил бы все данные

```
var data: [String: Any] = [:]
```

ключ к данным был бы в формате ГГГГ-М

записал бы данные так

```
data["2014-4"] = Weather(23.4, 3.1, 12)
```

А далее выводил бы списком все года, внутри годов месяца, и обращался бы к данным по году+месяцу, т.к. они нам известны.

При желании можно хранить месяцы внутри годов, а внутри месяцев уже данныe:

```
var data: [String: [Weather]] = [:]
data:["2014"].append[Weather(2.4, -13.1, 1)] //January
data["2014"].append[Weather(5.4, -2.1, 3)] //February
data["2014"].append[Weather(10.4, 3.1, 6)] //March
data["2014"].append[Weather(15.4, 3.1, 12)] //April
data["2014"].append[Weather(23.4, 3.1, 12)] //May
```

Список годов можно составить вручную

```
var yearsList: [Int] = []
for y in 2010...2017 {
    yearsList.append(y)
}
```

Месяца внутри годов одинаковые, это всегда диапазон 0...11.
Вообще на входе у Вас наверняка будет JSON с данными в котором будут и года и месяца, Вам лишь нужно будет все это записать в подготовленную выше структуру.

Comment: Сделал немного по-другому, но Ваш ответ очень помог. Спасибо! Извините, что ответил с опозданием.